# i want to turn an open edge loop into a single vertex, how do i do this

Tags: mesh

[image: open edge loop]

. i know this may have been asked before but isimply can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hit <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to merge the selected vertices into one. Or use the menu item *Mesh > Vertices > Merge*.

Comment: thank you, the first method worked, but bc the mirror modifier was there i had to mannually attach, but after that because of clipping it stayed. so thanks a bunch!